# D3 Scatterplot v6 unable to plot correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I have an issue with D3 scatterplot where the data are not correctly plot
(plotted to 1 horizontal line rather than a scattered plot, the actual data is also scattered)
and the x-axis not able to show up.

[image: scatterplot]

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
data = data.rows;

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  var momentTemp = moment(d[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
  var parseTemp = parseTime(momentTemp);
  d.date = parseTemp;
  d.close += d[1];
});

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.close;
})]);

var xValue = function(d) {
  return d.date;
}
var yValue = function(d) {
  return d.close;
}

// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });


// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + " ,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

[image: this is the sample of the data]

Answer (score 0):

That happens when your data is invalid. Are you sure the field `close` is correct? Your data calls the column `ratio`. I made some sample data and everything works:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%Z");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = new Array(100)
  .fill(undefined)
  .map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      date: new Date(Number(new Date("01/01/2000")) + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
      close: Math.random(),
    };
  });

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.close;
})]);

var xValue = function(d) {
  return d.date;
}
var yValue = function(d) {
  return d.close;
}

// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 1.5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d.close);
  });


// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + " ,0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```